# Problems with Router / URL Matcher class

Tags: php, regex, routes

since regular expressions aren't really my specialty, I need help with this little problem (in PHP).
I want to match a given url with an array of defined routes, e.g.:

```
$definedRoute = '/admin/user/[:id]/edit';
$url = '/admin/user/37/edit';
```

In my class, it would be like this, I imagine (getRoutes() returns an array of defined routes):

```
foreach ($this->getRoutes() as $route) {
        $pattern = '~' . preg_replace('~\[\:[a-z]+\]~', '[a-z0-9]+', 
str_replace('/', '\/', $route['definition'])) . '~';
        if (preg_match($pattern, $url)) {
            $parameters = $this->getRouteParameters($route['definition']);
            (new $route['class']())->{$route['method']}($parameters);
            // die? break?
        }
    }
```

I went about it like this: replace every occurence of a named parameter like [:id] with a regex for lowercase letters and numbers, e.g. `[a-z0-9]+`.
This would actually work but in some cases, it would match multiple and therefore the wrong routes. Also, it would always match `~\/~` in most cases. But every url should only be matched once.

Edit #1: the problem is: routes get matched multiple times. How can I prevent this?

Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: `but in some cases, it would match multiple` what cases?

Comment: This was mainly aiming at the case that the base route / would be matched instead of the desired defined route. Maybe a bad phrasing on my part.

Comment: I'm trying to find out what your current problem is. It's not stated clearly.

Comment: So there may be a few patterns that match on `/admin/user/37/edit`? and you want to avoid it?

Comment: No, I triple checked every route is defined only once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this will cover every conceivable case, but you can use `preg_match_all` or `preg_match` as opposed to iterating over the patterns.  It should also improve performance.

What this does is make the match order (left to right) important, with an array and loop you cannot do that (you can actually but it's uglier). Then we can sort the routes on complexity, like this:

```
//this is intentionally in the opposite order of what I want it.
$routes = ['definition' => ['\/', '\/admin\/user\/[a-z0-9]+\/']];

//the more / separators the closer to the beginning we want it. or the more complex regexs go first.
uasort($routes['definition'], function($a,$b){
    //count the number of / in the route
    //note the <=> spaceship (as it's called) is only available in PHP7+
    return substr_count($b, '/') <=> substr_count($a, '/');
});

$url = '/admin/user/37/edit';

//in regex the pipe | is OR
preg_match('~^('.implode('|', $routes['definition']).')~i', $url, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3ea2dcdc0c45024f18015667396d1670c9c01370)

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => /admin/user/37/edit
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => /admin/user/37/edit
        )

)
```

Which is correct in this case.  Even if you do get multiple matches, you can count the length of them `strlen` and then take the longest or "best" match from them.  This is pretty simple using `strlen` and probably sorting by length, so I will leave it up to you.

However I wouldn't call this a guarantee of it working 100% of the time, it's just the first thing that came to me.

**Another Idea**

Another idea is you are not anchoring the match to the start and end of the string.  In theory the route could/should match the entire string so with my above example if you add `^` and `$` here:

```
   preg_match('~^('.implode('|', $routes['definition']).')$~i', $url, $matches);
```

This will ensure a full match and in this case `~\/~` will not match even if the array is not sorted, as you can see in the sandbox below.

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/efd4a985359c6dd8b408a37c2f68fee815408c0c)

That said it's not inconceivable you would only have/need a partial match. This is up to you and how you build your routes and URLs. You can of course just use the `^` start as with a begins with type of match, but you would need to sort them in that case.

**Preg Match vs Preg Match All**

Preg match will also work, but it will only return the first match.  So if it matches multiple time you cannot compare them to find the best one.  This may be fine if you use `^` and `$`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is a reeeally interesting and,thb, intelligent concept. I'm hitting my head against the wall that I didn't come up with that. Gonna try this; looks promising.

Comment: I've used it for a Mediator ( event system ) before that has similar paths.  Or paths that are like URLs. such as `command/user/edit` etc.  For mine the neat thing is you could bind a function to match just `command` or `command/user` or `command/user/edit/:number` etc.  That worked in a similar way where the best match runs first then the others etc. (unless you tell the event to stop).  In short the same concept.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what exactly you mean by binding a function to it?

Comment: Not easily but look up [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) or just `call_user_func` but the first one is more useful IMO.  Basically you pass a function as a piece of data that is part of the Route (or whatever) and then when you match said route you execute the provided callback.

Comment: Typically I use the magic method `__invoke` and only use Object oriented concepts, but that's probably way above where you are.  Don't worry I only been doing PHP for like a decade now... lol

Comment: Hm, since I (in my current code) have an array which does not only contain the defined routes, but also the corresponding class and method name, I used `(new $route['class']())->{$route['method']}($parameters);`

Comment: That's fine too, you don't even need the `()` after the constructor ( unless you have args ).  `(new $route['class'])->{$route['method']}(...$parameters);`.  You can also use the `...` variadic which will "unwind" the $parmanters (if it's an array and you are using PHP7+, it might be 5.6 I can't remember.), and submit the elements as a separate argument.  I know "neat" right.

Comment: The nice thing with `call_user_func_array` is you would pass that like this `call_user_func_array([$route['class'], $route['method']], $parameters)`, but you can also use functions or Closures or classes with `__invoke`.  And if you put them as `$route['callback']` you can do it all with one piece of code. `call_user_func_array($route['callback'], $parameters)`

Comment: That's a really interesting and helpful train of thought.Just marked the answer as correct. Thank you! And btw. I know about argument unpacking. It's just it's only applicable in few scenarios.